# How to deal with month grouping and sum of hours of these months in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, formatting, string-formatting, google-query-language

I'm having trouble filtering a column by month/year and counting the unique values. I started trying with ARRAYFORMULA, then with QUERY, but without success.

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date | Start Time | End Time | Duration | **Month** | **Worked Days** | **Total Duration** |
| 01/06/2022 | 05:06 | 08:56 | 3h50min | **06/2022** | **9 days** | **31h47min** |
| 02/06/2022 | 05:08 | 08:43 | 3h35min | **07/2022** | **5 days** | **24h36min** |
| 02/06/2022 | 15:25 | 16:57 | 1h32min |  |  |  |
| 03/06/2022 | 05:13 | 08:24 | 3h11min |  |  |  |
| 04/06/2022 | 05:11 | 09:24 | 4h13min |  |  |  |
| 06/06/2022 | 13:05 | 14:36 | 1h31min |  |  |  |
| 07/06/2022 | 05:20 | 08:27 | 3h07min |  |  |  |
| 08/06/2022 | 05:08 | 08:52 | 3h44min |  |  |  |
| 09/06/2022 | 05:09 | 09:17 | 4h08min |  |  |  |
| 10/06/2022 | 05:11 | 08:07 | 2h56min |  |  |  |
| 01/07/2022 | 05:10 | 09:43 | 4h33min |  |  |  |
| 02/07/2022 | 05:23 | 07:43 | 2h20min |  |  |  |
| 04/07/2022 | 05:08 | 07:41 | 2h33min |  |  |  |
| 04/07/2022 | 20:57 | 21:59 | 1h02min |  |  |  |
| 05/07/2022 | 05:13 | 09:54 | 4h41min |  |  |  |
| 06/07/2022 | 05:10 | 09:38 | 4h28min |  |  |  |
| 06/07/2022 | 15:11 | 18:05 | 2h54min |  |  |  |
| 06/07/2022 | 20:00 | 22:05 | 2h05min |  |  |  |

Columns from A to D is what I have. Columns from E to G is what I expect.

One of the problems is that sometimes we have the day being repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({TEXT(A3:A; "mm/e")\ 
 IF(COUNTIFS(A3:A; A3:A; ROW(A3:A); "<="&ROW(A3:A))=1; 1; 0)\ C3:C-B3:B}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col3>0 
  group by Col1 label sum(Col2)'',sum(Col3)'' 
  format sum(Col3)'[h]\hmm\min'"))
```

[image]